# Are there web browsers that upload files using "multipart/mixed" inside "multipart/form-data"?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

According to the [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

> If the contents of a file are submitted with a form, the file input should be identified by the appropriate content type (e.g., "application/octet-stream"). If multiple files are to be returned as the result of a single form entry, they should be returned as "multipart/mixed" embedded within the "multipart/form-data".

I tried a simple HTML form with `<input type="file" name="files" multiple>` but when selecting multiple files in Chrome or Firefox, the serialized form simply has a regular MIME part for each file and no "multipart/mixed" part.

Are there web browsers that upload files using "multipart/mixed" inside "multipart/form-data" or was this part of the spec never implemented in practice?

Update 1: I tested the following browsers:

- Chrome 34
- Firefox 28
- Safari 7.0.3
- IE 11
- Opera 20

Update 2: I also tried with curl `curl -i -F secret=42 -F files=@foo.jpg -F files=@bar.jpg http://localhost:8080/` but it behaves the same as the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was needing to know the same thing, so just for anyone else who comes across this.

According to the [whatwg standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/), forms using `multipart/form-data` [should be encoded using RFC 7578](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#multipart-form-data):

> Encode the (now mutated) form data set using the rules described by RFC 7578, *Returning Values from Forms: multipart/form-data*, and return the resulting byte stream.

Taking a look at [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) we find [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.3):

> **4.3.  Multiple Files for One Form Field**
>
> The form data for a form field might include multiple files.
>
> [RFC2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) suggested that multiple files for a single form field be
> transmitted using a nested "multipart/mixed" part.  This usage is
> deprecated.
>
> To match widely deployed implementations, multiple files MUST be sent
> by supplying each file in a separate part but all with the same
> "name" parameter.
>
> Receiving applications intended for wide applicability (e.g.,
> multipart/form-data parsing libraries) SHOULD also support the older
> method of supplying multiple files.